Angular build process hangs at "Building..." and doesn't create dist folder
I am developing a system using Angular CLI: 17.3.9 and Node: 18.13.0. After finishing the development, when I run the command,
ng build

or
ng build --verbose

or
ng run build

the build process begins but never completes. It seems to stop halfway through and doesn't create the dist folder. The output looks like this:
You can read more about direct eval and bundling here: https://esbuild.github.io/link/direct-eval
⠴ Building...

  server.mjs                 1.1mb
  chunk-WZ3DHEP6.mjs       923.4kb
  chunk-6XD5BRK7.mjs       908.8kb
  chunk-JGCTGG76.mjs       522.4kb
  chunk-E5ACJJW7.mjs        11.8kb
  chunk-H6KHSOBK.mjs         2.8kb
  chunk-W6O7R4GF.mjs         2.2kb
  render-utils.server.mjs    1.5kb
  main.server.mjs            212b 
  chunk-CC4B4WUG.mjs         121b 


I’ve attempted to run the build commands (ng build, ng build --verbose, ng run build), but the process stops partway through with no dist folder generated.
I've also checked for possible memory issues or system limitations but didn't find any clear signs.
I expected the build process to complete successfully, creating the necessary output files in the dist folder, but it halts at the point mentioned above without producing the output.

My angular.json file contains,
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "reffelsystem": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "reffelsystem:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "reffelsystem:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "reffelsystem:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": [
              "src/**/*.ts",
              "src/**/*.html"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "f2af7aa0-94ef-4a1c-b2d7-7794087581ee",
    "schematicCollections": [
      "@angular-eslint/schematics"
    ]
  }
}

and my package.json file is,
{
  "name": "reffelsystem",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:reffelsystem": "node dist/reffelsystem/server/server.mjs",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^10.13.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "17.5.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.5.3",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.5.3",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "17.5.3",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.5.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^10.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "7.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "7.11.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}


can you provide your angular.json and package.json files?

I have added them. Please check and solve this.
